# Line with two anchor points kineticjs

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

Here is my current state: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewgable/Xr6mc/

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.0-beta2.js"></script>
    <script>
      var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 578,
        height: 200
      });

      var lineLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
      var flowerLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
      var centerLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

      var flower = new Kinetic.Group({
        x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
        y: stage.getHeight() / 2
      });

      // build stem
      var stem = new Kinetic.Line({
        strokeWidth: 10,
        stroke: 'green',
        points: [{
          x: flower.getX(),
          y: flower.getY()
        }, {
          x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
          y: stage.getHeight() + 10
        }]
      });

      // build center
      var center = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        radius: 6,
        fill: 'black',
        draggable: true,
        x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
        y: stage.getHeight() / 2
      });

      center.on('mouseover', function() {
        this.setFill('orange');
        flowerLayer.draw();
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      });

      center.on('mouseout', function() {
        this.setFill('black');
        flowerLayer.draw();
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
      });


      stage.on('mouseup', function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
      });

      lineLayer.add(stem);
      flowerLayer.add(flower);
      centerLayer.add(center);
      stage.add(lineLayer);
      stage.add(flowerLayer);
      stage.add(centerLayer);

      // keep step and flower position in sync with center
      center.on('dragstart', (function() {
        center.getLayer().afterDraw(function() {
          stem.attrs.points[0] = center.getPosition();
          flower.setPosition(center.getPosition());
          lineLayer.draw();
          flowerLayer.draw();
        });
      }));

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Just trying to make this line draggable (Easy, set it to drag).

And I want the line to have two anchor points, both can be draged in any direction.

As you can see I have only got to making one "anchor" point.

I cannot figure out the logic to make this possible, without the anchors moving about..

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Am not sure what you are trying to ask, at one point you want to make 2 anchors to control movement which you can do it just like u did for center, make sure the 2nd anchor is added after stem.
And secondly, you mention that you do not want to have anchors moving about.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewgable/QmJL9/1/) is the current state. You can drag the line. But when you do, the anchor point does not drag with the line. I tried to add it in a group, but doesn't seem to drag correctly. Also, I would like two circles on the line to drag either side.

Comment: do you have any particular reason for making so many different layers and clubbing these objects into groups. looks too complicated than needed

Comment: Not really, new to JavaScript!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/bxGMw/

The same logic can be copied right over from this page to what you want. You could just use a buildAnchors function to create the anchors for a shape, and an update function to redraw();

```
function buildAnchor(layer, x, y) {
            var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
                x: x,
                y: y,
                radius: 8,
                stroke: '#666',
                fill: '#ddd',
                strokeWidth: 2,
                draggable: true
            });

            // add hover styling
            anchor.on('mouseover', function() {
                document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                this.setStrokeWidth(4);
                layer.draw();
            });
            anchor.on('mouseout', function() {
                document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
                this.setStrokeWidth(2);
                layer.draw();
            });

            layer.add(anchor);
            return anchor;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code at the end and remove the code for `group1`

```
stem.on('dragmove', (function () {
  //  stem.getLayer().afterDraw(function () {
  center.setPosition([stem.getPosition().x + stem.getPoints()[0].x, stem.getPosition().y + stem.getPoints()[0].y]);
  c2.setPosition([stem.getPosition().x + stem.getPoints()[1].x, stem.getPosition().y + stem.getPoints()[1].y]);
  flower.setPosition(center.getPosition());
  lineLayer.draw();
  centerLayer.draw();
  flowerLayer.draw();
  //  });
}));

var c2 = new Kinetic.Circle({
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  radius: 6,
  fill: 'blue',
  draggable: true,
});
centerLayer.add(c2);
c2.on('dragstart', (function () {
  c2.getLayer().afterDraw(function () {
    stem.attrs.points[1].x = c2.getX()-stem.getX();
    stem.attrs.points[1].y = c2.getY()-stem.getY();
    lineLayer.draw();
    flowerLayer.draw();
  });
}));
```

Also change:

```
center.on('dragstart', (function () {
  center.getLayer().afterDraw(function () {
   stem.attrs.points[0].x = center.getX()-stem.getX();
   stem.attrs.points[0].y = center.getY()-stem.getY();    
   flower.setPosition(center.getPosition());
   lineLayer.draw();
   flowerLayer.draw();
  });
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help thus far, when you click the "anchor" or circle on the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N7HXL/1) after a drag it gets messed up. Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: Is there anyway the dots/ anchors can be drawn over the line? I would think that drawing them first would work. But doesn't seem to do it

Comment: u already have accepted an answer to this post... so isn't your problem solved. And is this question in context to my answer above? sorry but am not sure if I understand what you ask here

Comment: It may be solved, but I'm still trying to perfect the code. If you drag the line in your fiddle the line is being drawn over the dots. How would you get the dots to always be above the line.

Comment: to be sure that the dots are always on top, you can move the line to the bottom. just to stem.moveToBottom(), or c2.moveToTop()

Comment: all items in a layer have a z-index and are drawn according to that, so if you want to put them in a specific order of visibility, you can do .setZIndex(number); on them

Comment: So, I cleaned up the code. And then tried both setting the Z index and the move to the top/bottom still doesnt seem to work.. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewgable/N7HXL/17/)